# Need the chrome equivalent of these (Firefox) browser profile settings in Selenium Java

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

I have been playing around with Selenium Java WebDriver using chrome browser and have a fair amount of success so far. I have been able to start chrome window and send and receive data just fine. I now need to figure out the chrome equivalent of the following profile settings for Firefox browser.

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "image/jpg");
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "path/to/downloads/pics/folder");
```

Planning on doing something like this (ref: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities) but need set the other properties as above.

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
//set the rest of the preferences for chrome as shown above for Firefox
```

- Selenium: 2.47.1
- Mac: OsX Yosemite
- ChromeDriver: 2.18
- JDK: 1.8x

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026391/setting-chrome-preferences-w-selenium-webdriver-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();  
    options.addArguments("--browser.download.folderList=2");
    options.addArguments("--browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk=image/jpg");
    options.addArguments("--browser.download.dir=path/to/downloads/pics/folder");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Thanks Shubhasmit, I'll try this soon. Accepting answer.

Comment: Could you add a link to the documentation where those options are referenced?