# Downloading a file at a specified location through python and selenium using Chrome driver

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, download, driver

I am trying to automatically download some links through selenium's click functionality and I am using a **chrome webdriver** and python as the programming language. **How can I select the download directory** through the python program so that it does not get downloaded in the default Downloads directory. I found a solution for firefox but there the download dialog keeps popping up every time it clicks on the link which does not happen in Chrome.

Comment: Go to chrome settings and check Ask to save each file before downloading

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setting Chrome preferences w/ Selenium Webdriver in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026391/setting-chrome-preferences-w-selenium-webdriver-in-python)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Update 2018:

Its not valid Chrome command line switch, see the [source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc) use [hoju answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43789674/458214) below to set the Preferences.

> Original:

You can create a profile for chrome and define the download location for the tests. Here is an example:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("download.default_directory=C:/Downloads")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: Why do you need to `import Options`?

Comment: This does not appear to work.  Perhaps Chromedriver's interface has changed?  hoju's response appears to work now.

Comment: it's not work if we want download a video..video show on chrome instead of download...How download video now?

Comment: It's not work for me in mac, just try ans below: `prefs = {'download.default_directory' : '/path/to/dir'};
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)`

Comment: This answer is deprecated. Acceptable answer should be changed to Hoju's.

Comment: How to change the default directory after Webdriver started? How to get the name of file downloaded?

Answer (score 134):

I found the accepted solution didn't work, however this slight change did:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {'download.default_directory' : '/path/to/dir'}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Thanks! This really solve my problem. However, it seems not working for relative path. e.g. D:/ddd works while ./tmp does not. The ./tmp (relative path) ends up poping up a dialog for me to manually choose the directory...

Comment: Is there a way to change download path while on **current session**, similar to how you click Chrome Settings->Download ? The answer I saw always incur **building new option + new driver + get a whole new session** . I would wish not to close the current session, since my folder separation based on each item in a drop-down list and there's no need to reload a new page. There are thousands of items in that drop-down; the accepted method means closing and loading the page thousands times.

Comment: It's works! Mac `google chrome 78.0.3904.97` and `chromedriver  2.40`

Comment: How to change the default directory after WebDriver started?

Comment: How to get the name of file downloaded?

Comment: chrome_options is deprecated

Comment: Doesn't work for me and I am getting a download error. Code works fine for default download directory though (Windows)

Comment: Code worked for me and I don't get any down error. Also Chrome_Options is deprecated so I used options instead 
earlier the path was  C:/Users/myusname/drivers/DownloadFiles
I changed it to C:\Users\myusname\drivers\DownloadFiles\\

downloadFilepath = r"C:\Users\myusname\drivers\DownloadFiles\\";
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : downloadFilepath}
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs) 
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver,options=options)
Solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42943611/1604050

Comment: @Kenny is this possible. Did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 15):

the exact problem I also have faced while trying to do exactly same what you want to :)

For **chrome**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
prefs = {"profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
             "download.default_directory": 
                        r"C:\Users\user_dir\Desktop\\",#IMPORTANT - ENDING SLASH V IMPORTANT
             "directory_upgrade": True}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
browser=webdriver.Chrome(<chromdriver.exe path>, options=options)
```

For **Firefox**:
follow this blog for the answer:
https://srirajeshsahoo.wordpress.com/2018/07/26/how-to-bypass-pop-up-during-download-in-firefox-using-selenium-and-python/

The blog says all about the pop-up and downloads dir and how to do

Answer (score 5):

Using prefs solved my problem

```
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
prefs = {"download.default_directory":path}
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('../harveston/chromedriver.exe',options = options)
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me on Chrome `v81.0.4044.138`

```
preferences = {
                "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
                "download.default_directory": os.getcwd() + os.path.sep,
                "directory_upgrade": True
            }

chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', preferences)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/usr/bin/chromedriver", options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: This one is working also on `Chrome 80.0.3987.149`. I tried the other answers above and they didn't work on my Ubuntu machine. Thanks @CodeWalker

Comment: ditto for working with 81.0.4044.69.
needs add of chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

Comment: also: webdriver.Chrome(options=blah) supercedes webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=blah)   
I would use a variable name other than chrome_options or options to avoid confusion.

Comment: The chrome_options is deprecated now. And if I use the options as mentioned in previous comment does not work(I wonder why it is not working). The above code works in my Mac of Chrome Version 83

Answer (score 1):

I see that many people have the same problem, just add the backslash at the end

> ```
> op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
> prefs = {'download.default_directory' : 'C:\\Users\\SAJComputer\\PycharmProjects\\robot-test\\'}
> op.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
> driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path , options=op)
> ```

Comment: Instead of using double backslash in the path you can convert the path as raw string using r'C:\Users\SAJComputer\PycharmProjects\robot-test'

Answer (score 1):

Update 2022:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()

prefs = {"download.default_directory" : "C:\YourDirectory\Folder"}

options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
```

Comment: What is Service in this case? it not defined before

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux distribution

Use this code

```
prefs = {'download.prompt_for_download': False,
         'download.directory_upgrade': True,
         'safebrowsing.enabled': False,
         'safebrowsing.disable_download_protection': True}

options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
driver.desired_capabilities['browserName'] = 'ur mum'
params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': r'C:\chickenbutt'}}
driver.execute("send_command", params)
```

Answer (score 0):

To provide download directory and chrome's diver executable path use the following code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("download.default_directory=C:/Your_Directory")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options ,executable_path='C:/chromedriver')
```

change the path in your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippet holds good for Windows/linux/MacOs distro:

```
    downloadDir = f"{os.getcwd()}//downloads//"
    # Make sure path exists.
    Path(downloadDir).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    
    # Set Preferences.
    preferences = {"download.default_directory": downloadDir,
                   "download.prompt_for_download": False,
                   "directory_upgrade": True,
                   "safebrowsing.enabled": True}

    chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chromeOptions.add_argument("--window-size=1480x560")
    chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER_PATH, options=chromeOptions)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's for relative path:

```
download_directory = os.path.abspath('./tmp')
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {'download.default_directory' : download_directory}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Answer (score -8):

This is non code level solution with no chrome profiling/options settings.

**If you are using script only on your local machine then use this solution**

Click on Menu -> Setting -> Show advanced settings... -> Downloads

Now uncheck

Ask where to save each file before downloading

[image]

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: This question is about controlling chrome through an automated system called selenium. You answered as if he asked about controlling chrome manually.

Comment: It's a one time configuration you have to made and yes it's a solution too

Comment: This is actually a valid and working answer. It worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Please rate this answer .. I need to remove it if it will have negative rating

Comment: Shubam had answered it well. Set your chrome profile's default directory and then it will be the solution.

Comment: The goal is to change this configuration through Selenium and not manually... the whole point of Selenium is to automatize.

Comment: Doesn’t you all guys just look it at a solution for local as I said and if not work then downgrade me .. so if I delete this working solution and no one else can see even if useful for them does that make all happy?