# How do I get the Download Directory Location from Chrome Using Python

Tags: python, google-chrome

I have a script that downloads a file and then does some sorting with the data in the file
different users use their own downloads directory
my example being that I actually use a Dropbox Folder as my default windows downloads folder so I can share files between work and home easily.
(I have moved my default downloads directory into Dropbox using the properties dialog when you right click on the downloads folder in windows)
so I have the need to figure out how to get that download file directory info 
Currently using Selenium and Chromium to perform the download action

Changing the actual download location is not an option..period

I tried using glob to pull the system downloads folder, but it always returns the C:\Users\Username\Downloads directory.... which is wrong in my case and many other users cases

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35331854/downloading-a-file-at-a-specified-location-through-python-and-selenium-using-chr)

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("download.default_directory=C:/Downloads")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```