# Download file to default location selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying the following lines

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

opt = Options()

opt.headless = True
opt.add_experimental_option ("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9090")
opt.add_argument("download.default_directory=C:/Users/Future/Desktop")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:/Webdrivers/chromedriver.exe", options=opt)
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

The file is downloaded but in the Downloads folder although I tried in the code to change the path of the default folder.

The code is designed to run on an already open browser. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Downloading a file at a specified location through python and selenium using Chrome driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35331854/downloading-a-file-at-a-specified-location-through-python-and-selenium-using-chr)

Comment: I already tried the solutions on the link but the file is downloaded in the Downloads folder.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for `.add_experimental_option(...`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

opt = Options()
opt.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": r"C:/Users/Future/Desktop",
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
  "safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled": False,
  "safebrowsing.enabled": False
})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:/Webdrivers/chromedriver.exe', options=opt)
url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68114651/download-file-to-default-location-selenium-python/68115019#68115019'

# Load URL
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. i tried the code and I got `InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: cannot parse capability: goog:chromeOptions
from invalid argument: unrecognized chrome option: prefs`

Comment: @YasserKhalil I updated the answer to open the webpage of this question with the options loaded.  If this does not work for you, what version of Python and Chrome are you running?

Comment: Thanks a lot. In fact, I am working on an open browser using this approach:  using cmd I typed `cd C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application` then `chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9090 --user-data-dir="D:\Webdrivers\MyProfile"` then navigating to the url which requires credentials manually then, at last, I ran the python code to begin the download process. Hope this information helps.

Comment: @YasserKhalil When you navigate to the url are you going to `http://localhost:9090`? This is the part I am getting stuck.

Comment: This is as a port for the selenium code to work on so as to work on that instance of chrome. I am using that instance to navigate to my website and doing some steps manually then finally to run the code.