# How can I download a csv file from a website whose element is a button or rather the csv is accessible via a button?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I'm trying to download or rather read a csv from a website. The csv is hidden under a button. Here is the [website link.](https://defillama.com/chains)

The csv I'm trying to save is on the furthest right and is denoted as a blue button labelled **'Download all data in .csv'**

Here is a sample code I tried to use to download it, but the download fails:

```
# import the required libraries
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : "D:/Profession/Data Extraction and Web Scraping/Stocks Data Extraction - Core Scientific/Output"}

#example: prefs = {"download.default_directory" : "C:\Tutorial\down"};
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:/Software/Selenium WebDrivers/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver", options=options)

try:
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.get("https://defillama.com/chains")
    downloadcsv = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'sc-8f0f10aa-1')
    download_button = downloadcsv.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')
    download_button.click() # this should save it to the folder I specified in prefs
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.close()
except:
    print('There is an Error!')
```

This code tries to download the csv, however the download fails. Is there a better way I could download the CSV, especially one that is under a button? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to use a proper wait method.
`implicitly_wait` waits for element **presence** while you need to wait for element to be **clickable**, this is more mature element state. `WebDriverWait` is the best practice to be used in such (and almost all the others) cases.
The following code works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://defillama.com/chains"

driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".sc-8f0f10aa-1 button"))).click()
```

Comment: Only that I can't control the exact file path I need to download it to. Is there a way I can configure that so I can point it to the file location of my choice? Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome! Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35331854/downloading-a-file-at-a-specified-location-through-python-and-selenium-using-chr