# Close Selenium and Download

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

*Hello, I Have Automatic Downloading Python Script:*

Below is the **CODE**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


links = [
'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AqCXX1ZK9bo'

]

for link in links:
    browser=webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\\Downloads\chromedriver')
    browser.get('https://www.onlinevideoconverter.com/pt/youtube-converter')


    ak=browser.find_element_by_id('texturl')
    ak.send_keys(link)

    au = WebDriverWait(browser, 40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[text() = "Começar"]')) )
    au.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    af = WebDriverWait(browser, 90).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'downloadq'))
)

    browser.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', af)
```

When and activating the

```
af = WebDriverWait(browser, 90).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'downloadq'))
    )

        browser.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', af)
```

And Generated a Download in the Chrome bar. And My Goal is that When the Download reaches 100% the Tab will automatically close with a **`browser.close`**

**What is missing?**

Comment: don't you get error message when you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe ? I get some error when I run your code.

Comment: Error No, But Changed to Your Webdriver Directory?

Comment: it is strange because you forgot to `import time`

Comment: It is missing Because it was a down but can disregard it was needing to close the page with the download reach 100%

Comment: always put working code - don't expect that will correcting mistakes like this.

Comment: as I know Selenium gives access to displayed page but not to other elements in browser so you can only check in folder if file was downloaded - [python selenium, find out when a download has completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338897/python-selenium-find-out-when-a-download-has-completed) or you can use other modules to download it and then you can close widow at once.

Comment: and you would tell me how I change the standard directories of the downloads

Comment: always use Google before ask: [Selenium Webdriver in Python - files download directory change in Chrome preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026391/selenium-webdriver-in-python-files-download-directory-change-in-chrome-prefere)

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess the easiest approach will be **not** to click the download button but to get the download link and then you can simply use `urllib.retrieve()` function to get the video downloaded locally in your system.
I guess this would be the best approach. Hope this helps :)

Comment: But I Need to See the Process Getting there I need to close each tab when it reaches 100% .but thanks

Comment: I can give you another solution to close the chrome tab but that would be very unrealistic approach. You can use PyAutoGUI. Go to the following link: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#examples Mainly this can be used to find gui items on screen, here `100%` and when it finds `100%` you can close the chrome tab in the same manner.