# Can't download file through Selenium chrome webdriver in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium webdriver to scrape a website and download a file from it to a folder. for some reason, if I change the default download path of chrome through `ChromeOptions()`, when I `click()` the download link, the file shows `failed - download error` in the download bar at the bottom of the window. I made sure chrome and chrome driver are up to date but it still doesn't work.

Here is the code i'm using to change the default download path.

```
from selenium import webdriver

download_path = select_directory()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
preferences = {"download.default_directory": download_path}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

And here is the code i'm using to download the file itself.

```
from selenium import webdriver

table = browser.find_element_by_id("tblDocs")
documents_info = table.find_elements_by_class_name("clsTableRowNormal")
for document in documents_info:
    str = document.find_element_by_class_name("clsTableCell").text
    if str.find("תשריט") > -1:
        document.find_element_by_tag_name("img").click()
```

Does anyone know how I can download the file to a specific directory?
I thought of maybe downloading the file to the default folder and moving the file from there to my desired path, but I don't know how to get the default folder through selenium.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Update the question with relevant HTML of the element.

Comment: Try this hope it  helps:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026391/selenium-webdriver-in-python-files-download-directory-change-in-chrome-prefere

Comment: `downLoadFolder =os.path.join( os.getenv('USERPROFILE'), 'Downloads')` this will give you the default downloads folder path.

Answer (score 2):

So apparently selenium can't download to a path with a `/` in it's path string.
I had to change `select_directory()` to return a file path string using only `\\`.
Thanks for the help!