# Unable to set custom download path Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I set the download path as :

```
username = getpass.getuser()
download_path = "download.default_directory=C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\Desktop"
options = Options()
options.add_argument(download_path)
```

But it's not working at all. How to solve it? or why it's happening?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: try `("download.default_directory", download_path)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium Webdriver in Python - files download directory change in Chrome preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026391/selenium-webdriver-in-python-files-download-directory-change-in-chrome-prefere)