# Download a file from clicking event using Selenium on Google Colaboratory?

Tags: python, selenium, csv, button, google-colaboratory

I am scraping a website that clicks on a button to download a csv using python and selenium.
So far the code works perfectly on my local machine and the files are downloaded onto my machine. But I would like to run the code on google colaboratory, resulting in the downloaded files storing onto my google drive.

This problem is very similar to
[How can I download a file from clicking event using Selenium on Colaboratory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68458607/how-can-i-download-a-file-from-clicking-event-using-selenium-on-colaboratory)

I followed the google drive mounting procedure, but still cannot find my supposed downloaded files.

I'm not sure how to get the files to save on a cloud drive.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.