# using google chrome's downloader - python 3

Tags: python, google-chrome, python-3.x

I'm trying to download files using python 3. I use `webbrowser.open_new(url)` to open file locations. some files are downloaded automatically by chrome's downloader, and some are just opened in a chorme window. How can I choose between the options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot influence that, not with the Python `webbrowser` module.

What is downloaded and what is displayed in the browser is a preference set in the browser itself.

You *could* try and set those preferences using Selenium, see [Set chrome.prefs with python binding for selenium in chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165593/set-chrome-prefs-with-python-binding-for-selenium-in-chromedriver). This is not going to be simple; you'll need to figure out the exact preference strings to alter. Perhaps the [Chromium prefences list](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/configuring-other-preferences) can be used as a guide there.

Answer (score 0):

The Web server on which the file is hosted sends a header that suggests to the browser how it might handle the file, and the user's preferences hold some sway as well. You likely won't be able to override it easily.

You can avoid this by not using a Web browser from Python. `urllib2` or better yet, the third-party `requests` module is a much easier way to talk to the Web.