# Chrome Debugger Api Attach Extension Error

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, selenium, google-chrome-extension, selenium-webdriver

**Task:** Debug other extensions using [chrome debugger api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger).

**Expected Output:** http request logs made by other installed extensions.

**Method:** Running chrome webdriver with selenium in python setting flag `chromeopts.add_argument('--silent-debugger-extension-api' )`. Inside my extension, On event **chrome.management.onInstalled** using following code

`chrome.debugger.attach({ extensionId: info.id }, version, onAttach.bind(null, info.id));
 chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ extensionId: info.id }, "Network.enable");
 chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener(onEvent);`

**Error:** *Cannot access a chrome-extension:// URL of different extension*

Comment: Make sure the flag is actually active; it should be visible at `chrome://version/`

Comment: thanks @Xan.I can only see these flags _Command Line "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end_  guess you are right flag is not setting. Is chromeopts.add_argument('--silent-debugger-extension-api')  not correct command? Any alternative way of setting it automatically?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience with webdriver. But it's a reasonable suspicion.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15165593/934239) may help.

Comment: I have manually enable the flag from chrome://flags but still got the same error. Is it a problem of chrome? is this function allowed even?

Comment: Again, as much as I know Chrome extension API, this is something I don't know. It's possible that this is not allowed, but docs are unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To debug the background page of another extension, you need to set two flags:

- `--silent-debugger-extension-api`
  To allow debugging of background pages.
- `--extensions-on-chrome-urls`
  To allow debugging of other extensions.

Comment: What an excellent answer. Thank you for helping. Also can you tell me will this only store xhrhtmlrequest from background script? what about contentscript?

Comment: @muhammadharis Do not ask follow-up questions in comments. We're here to help if you ask a new one.

Comment: @RobW I've created a docs issue about it, I'd be great if you could triage it: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=504494