# Chrome Debugger Api Attach Extension: Content Script

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-extension

**Task:** Collect http requests within content scripts of other extensions

**Description:** I am aware that we can attach debugger using [chrome debugger api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) with an extension **background page**. However, official documentation haven't clearly mentioned if we can also collect requests made in content scripts of extensions?

**Note:** This question can be a followup of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31054482/chrome-debugger-api-attach-extension-error/) question.

Comment: I have implemented method and able to get the http requests attached to extensions. However, I am not sure these http requests include only the one made from background or also from content scripts as well.

Comment: include code in the question. seems like since you already implemented it its a matter of just trying it. what results you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have done some testing and find out that debugger is attached to only background page. Which means that only http requests from background will be recorded.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you'll have to attach to the page itself in which the content script lives, because that's where those requests originate.

Comment: but in that case is there anyway of differentiating requests triggered by page and the ones by context scripts of other extension?