# add_experimental_option() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, chrome-options

I used the following code according to this post [Set chrome.prefs with python binding for selenium in chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165593/set-chrome-prefs-with-python-binding-for-selenium-in-chromedriver)

```
chroptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions

chroptions.add_experimental_option('prefs',{'download.default_directory' : 'C:\\Users\\elek2'})

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path ='C:\\Users\\elek2\\AppData\\Local\\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options = chroptions)
```

and I get this error:

```
TypeError: add_experimental_option() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
```

What am I doing wrong...

Comment: You didn't pass an argument called `'value'` into `add_experimental_option()` function

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't clarify a lot... isn't {'download.default_directory' : 'C:\\Users\\elek2'} a value?

Comment: try to pass `value={'download.default.....` as argument

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. thanks anyway

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create an instance of Options. Currently you're just accessing the class itself.

```
chroptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
```